# Quartz-Mongo Db Integration- Index Creation Issue

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

**Overview:**
I am using the Quartz Scheduler framework with Spring Batch and MongoDb to maintain the quartz_job, scheduler, locks, etc. collections in Mongo Db and maintaining the job details there itself. I am able to successfully run the application using the above set up till the quartz framework has access to create INDEXES to the above `collections(quartz_job,quartz_scheduler, quartz_locks,quartz_trigger, etc)`.

**Problem Statement**
But in the Professional world, Quartz won't be authorized to create indexes, which is why when I am trying to connect to secured `Mongo DB` (which does not authorize to create index) it is throwing the below exception:

> Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error: 'not authorized on quartz_jobs_test to execute command { createIndexes: "quartz__jobs", indexes: [ { key: { keyGroup: 1, keyName: 1 }, name: "keyGroup_1_keyName_1", ns: "quartz_jobs_test.quartz__jobs", unique: true } ] }

**Questions:**

1. Is there any option for the Quartz framework to bypass creating an index of its own?
2. Will Quartz automatically by-pass creating an index, if I create the index in those collections manually, even though it does not have access to create an index.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: How did you configure Quartz to connect to MongoDB?

Comment: org.quartz.jobStore.class=com.novemberain.quartz.mongodb.MongoDBJobStore

org.quartz.jobStore.mongoUri=mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/MyDBName?ssl=true

org.quartz.jobStore.dbName: MyDBName

org.quartz.jobStore.collectionPrefix=quartz_

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=quartzMongoInstance

Comment: Does the user account specified by `username` have the `readWrite` role for the `quartz_jobs_test` database?

Comment: Yes it has username and read write access.. Only I dont have access to create indexes...

Comment: I Think in MongoDBJobStore, there is a method called ensureIndexes.. which is trying to drop and create new collection and indexes... if that is the reason.. not sure how to stop the application not doing that...